# How to split screen in Windows 10 with multiple mice and keyboards?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, split-window

so I'm using Windows 10 and I'd like to split screen my monitor (1080p) into two screens (like with the split functionally that Windows has built in), but being able to for example play games in one side and work on the other one. Obviously this isn't possible normally because when you click on a window, the other one becomes inactive. I'm currently using Pluralinput to get two separetly mice and keyboards and it works fine, I just want two individual screens on the same monitor. Is this even possible? Thanks in advance!